# Extjs5 grid: stopping events from execute before onSelect event finish

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs-grid

I have a gridView that have both onSelect and onItemMouseDown events.

when I click a cell, and print its position it gives the past ones. If I put the position printing code inside a setTimeOut timer for lets say 100ms, the position is true.

Is there a way to postpone the events on gridView until the position is updated for the newly selected cell?

thanks..

Comment: What event are you listening to for your print code? Can you please post some reference code?

Comment: have you tried afterrender?  I'm pretty sure it gets fired every time a grid repaint occurs, which would be true when you click on a cell.

beforecellclick should also have the new cell's information